# Export old Google Bookmarks to equivalent tool

Tags: bookmarks, google-bookmarks

I have been using google bookmarks for a LONG time and have many well tagged and described bookmarks stored there. As google is closing this service I need to move them to a new service (perhaps pocket or raindrop.io) but I have encountered a major problem.

All sources say to use the export bookmarks facility in Google bookmarks but this utility just produces a simple html file with folders and links it does not include the description fields or the tags associated with a bookmark making it basically useless to me.

I need to export the tags and descriptions into some kind of format I can use to import them into an equivalent tool.

Is there a way to extract all the known data from google bookmarks?

Answer (score 2):

I found a useful path here although not for the faint of heart.

you can use a modified URL to get full data from bookmarks as XML by putting this URL into the browser:

> https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml

Saving this to a file and converting it to csv using an online converter (I used https://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm)

Now you can load the full data into a spreadsheet package and manipulate it into the required import format. (I used a few simple formula to transform the file into the required csv input for raindrop.io)

And eventually I got it to work.